# What's the recommended shell in emacs?

Tags: emacs

There are some shells in emacs. As a emacs newbie, i want to know what's your preferred shell using emacs ?

Now i am using eshell but sometimes the ansi-term seems better.

Regards!

Comment: This question is a bit confused. Emacs *does* have a built-in shell (`eshell`), but it only has the one. All other shells are external processes. `ansi-term` is a terminal emulator (it prompts you for a program to run, and by default that's a shell, but it can be anything). `M-x shell` similarly runs an external shell, but uses `shell-mode` to interact with it instead of term.el's terminal emulator. Do you want to compare `eshell` with other shells, or do you want to compare the different ways of interfacing with some external shell?

Comment: eshell is good but it expose the root's password when running "sudo ...".

Comment: @z_axis: That's completely false. I've just tried with a bare Emacs24 (`emacs -Q`) and it just works as expected out of the box, that is, it doesn't show your password but uses the minibuffer.

Comment: ~ $ sudo pkg_info -Qx emacs
password：abc123

Answer (score 2):

I use [multi-term](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm). As it's name indicated, you can open multiple terms. there is a feature I like most is that I can open a term in current window.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") 'multi-term-dedicated-open)
```

The term's pwd is the same as the file I am editing.